# Calling SetThreadExecutionState before locking PC

Tags: c#, kernel32

I have a program which triggers evens when a user locks and unlocks their computer. I have added a function to keep the PC awake and unlocked if the user wants by calling the following code:

```
private void changeUnlockState()
{
    uint status = NativeMethods.SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE.ES_CONTINUOUS | EXECUTION_STATE.ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED);    //Call ex state method with correct flags
    if (status == 0)
    {
        couldNotChangeStateError();
    }
}

internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern uint SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE esFlags);
}

[FlagsAttribute]
public enum EXECUTION_STATE : uint
{
    ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED = 0x00000040,
    ES_CONTINUOUS = 0x80000000,
    ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = 0x00000002,
    ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = 0x00000001
    // Legacy flag, should not be used.
    // ES_USER_PRESENT = 0x00000004
}
```

The function `changeUnlockState` is called when the program first starts (so the computer can't lock), is called when the user locks the computer to allow the screen to go to sleep, and again when they unlock to resume not locking the computer due to inactivity.

It appears to work fine initially, but not after the computer has been locked and unlocked. Is there some resetting of this parameter which happens automatically anyway? I have looked at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373208%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I can't find anything about what happens if the computer is locked manually (other than it won't override user input). Should I only call the change state function  on a unlock, or not at all?

Comment: Hmm, this shouldn't work at all.  It can, at best, prevent the screen-saver from popping up but it can't prevent a workstation lock.

Comment: Hmmm, my mouse is very sensitive, maybe I've been accidentally knocking the desk and just thinking it didn't lock.
Is there any way you can recommend to prevent workstation locks?

Comment: Other than moving them mouse by one pixel :P
Also this is where I got the idea from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600627/prevent-windows-workstation-desktop-from-locking-while-running-a-wpf-program